# Identify this indoor plant with strange stem-like leaves

Tags: species-identification, botany, trees

It appears that this plant branches multiple times from the base of its stem; however, I'm not sure if the base stems are from one organism. It becomes yellowish in color at the tip each stem-like leaves; one node can branch 3-4 leaves at a time.

Additional information:
As for the specimen location- I am currently living in Japan and this plant was bought as a gift for me. It probably is imported from other countries since it doesn't seem to be native here. For maintenance; I was told to just cut the tip of the leaves if it began to fade in color and die; and water the plant at least once a week.

[image: plant]

Comment: 1. What's your location?   2.  What happens  when  you  break off a stem?

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer --  I'm glad it answered your question. However, please **update your question with the information I requested in my previous comment** so that the question can serve better use to others in the future. In general, species ID questions should always contain some information about the specimen's location. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a **Pencil Tree** (***Euphorbia tirucalli***), sometimes called "pencil plant", "pencil cactus" or "milkbush." This "leafless-looking" plant is not actually a cactus, but actually a "Euphorbia" (i.e., member of the [Euphorbiaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphorbiaceae) family), and should present a white "milky" liquid [latex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latex) when broken.

- CAUTION: [**THIS IS A POISONOUS PLANT**](https://www.uaex.edu/yard-garden/resource-library/plant-week/pencil-cactus.aspx) [See symptoms [here](https://plants.ces.ncsu.edu/plants/all/euphorbia-tirucalli/)].

[image]

[image: Flora de Filipinas ... Gran edicion ... Atlas I...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Euphorbia_tirucalli_Blanco1.210b.png]

**Description:** A succulent, spineless shrub with round, green branches; leaves clustered at the tip of the branches and soon dropping

- Although it eventually can grow into a small-sized tree in its natural habitat, this plant is found more commonly as a medium-sized house plant or landscaping "shrub."

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Euphorbia_tirucalli_0001.jpg]

[image: http://www.succulents.us/euphotir.html]

**Range:** Tropical Africa and India

> *Euphorbia tirucalli* is very well adapted to semi-arid conditions, but also occurs in both dry and moist forest, savanna and shrub land, and withstands salt stress associated with coastal conditions, but no frost. It occurs from sea-level up to 2500 m altitude. It grows well on a wide variety of light-textured, neutral to acidic soils. It is commonly associated with human settlements and becomes naturalized rapidly. It is locally common and often occurs in groups. [[Source](http://database.prota.org/PROTAhtml/Euphorbia%20tirucalli_En.htm)].

Answer (score 0):

I would say it looks like some kind of [Rhipsalis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhipsalis). Which exact species i can't tell. Just search for images of Rhipsalis and compare to yours.

**EDIT:**

Some time ago i had a specimen of *rhipsalis baccifera* which looked a lot like your plant but wasn't as self supporting as yours. It was hanging down below its pot. But maybe yours is some kind of subspecies.